# install 2 qt builds on the same machine

Tags: qt, qmake

I've been using static built Qt 5.0.2 built in this directory
`D:\Soft\programming\qt-5.4.2`.

Now I have installed the prebuilt `qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline` to `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2`

qmake location as shown in QtCreator configuration is `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\qmake.exe` 
and compiler : `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`

qmake location for the static version is
`D:\Soft\programming\qt-5.4.2\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe` and compiler
`Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0 (x86)`

Upon building a test program, I get several warnings of the form below.

> C:\Users\Bill\Desktop\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri:8: error: WARNING: Include file D:/Soft/programming/qt-5.0.1/qtbase/mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_sql.pri not found`

I used to ignore these errors in my static built qt. An example is

> C:\Users\Bill\Documents\QtProjects\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri:8: error: WARNING: Include file D:/Soft/programming/qt-5.4.2/qtbase/mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_sql.pri not found

Now, i get the warning and errors ;

```
:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option '-wl,-enable-auto-import'
:-1: error: error: wl: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option '-wl'
```

As a major concern, `D:/Soft/programming/qt-5.0.1/` does not exists from the warnings of the prebuild in contrast to the existing `D:/Soft/programming/qt-5.4.2` in the warning from the static build.

I'm guessing this new installation is reading configuration and qmake files from the static build directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are switching Qt versions you must do a 'nmake distclean' in your project folder (from a terminal or perhaps your IDE), then run qmake using from the version/path you want to build against. Otherwise old paths linger in your makefiles. A 'make clean' is not enough.